ACI cannot access container from ACR when set up with terraform: InaccessibleImage
I'm trying to set up ACI using terraform, but as the title states it doesn't seem to be able to access the ACR registry.
│ Error: creating Container Group (Subscription: "redacted"
│ Resource Group Name: "myresourcegoup"
│ Container Group Name: "mycontainergroup): performing ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate: containerinstance.ContainerInstanceClient#ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="InaccessibleImage" Message="The image 'mycompany.azurecr.io/myimage:latest' in container group 'mycontainergroup' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."

Here's a minimal example to reproduce it:
resource "azurerm_container_group" "generic" {
  name                = local.aci_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = "myresourcegroup"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  ip_address_type     = "None"  # Specifies that no IP is assigned

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    # real deal has the identity coming from previous steps but fails even like this
    identity_ids = ["/subscriptions/redacted/resourceGroups/myresourcegrouo/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/myidentity"]

  }
  container {
    name   = local.aci_name
    image  = "mycompany.azurecr.io/myimage:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"
  }
  # No ports block needed since no network access is required
}

Things I have tried/checked include but are not limited to:

The container is accessible and I can pull it just fine using docker pull
The identity given to ACI does very much have AcrPull enabled for ACR
It also fails when I manually give the identity even more rights, even full Owner rights
I am getting the same InaccessibleImage error even when I use an image that doesn't exist in my ACR repo, or when I use an invalid ACR repo there.
If I try to use an invalid identity I will get a different error, so it does not seem to be just ignoring the given identity
Checked this with three different SotA LLM models + 2 infra guru friends of mine -> no help, so getting really desperate. Still don't want to click these from UI manually like some sort of a caveman


Classic, battled with this for ages and then pretty much immediately stumbled upon a solution.
Apparently the cause was that it is not using the given identity to authenticate to ACR, but doing it this way did the trick:
image_registry_credential {
    server   = "mycompany.azurecr.io"
    user_assigned_identity_id = var.identity_resource_id
  }


You, Sir, are a hero and a scholar. I had the exact same problem.
